# Role Checking Before Access

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm attempting to make a User System from Laravel, and I have a plan to give certain users "BETA Tester" role so that they can access the beta side of the site.

However, I am unsure if this is even possible and how I would even go about doing it.

The sort of plan i'm looking for is 'Navigation To Beta Section Of The Site > Big Log In [SKIP IF ALREADY LOGGED IN] > Check If The User Has The "BETA Tester" role > If Yes Send Them To The Beta Site / If No Tell Them They Do Not Have Access'

Is this possible?

Comment: sure, its just a role check in a middleware

Comment: How would i go about doing this? do you have skype or discord or anything I can communicate this with? I'm trying to learn laravel, and it's a big change haha

Comment: @lagbox Sorry, forgot to tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom middleware class that checks the user's role:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Checkrole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // hasRole being a function defined on your User model that checks
        // a user's assigned role(s).
        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole('BETA Tester')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(401, 'You are not allowed to access this page');
    }
}
```

Comment: By chance, do you have a discord or skype that I can communicate with you with?